# TryCatch for if two extents?

Tags: r, error, extents

I have some spatial processing in R that I want to do.  After selecting out the appropriate polygon (`clip1`) I want to crop the raster on that polygon with the command `clip1 <- crop(imported_raster, extent(single))`

However, occasionally I get an error `Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap` because `clip1` is not within imported_raster

```
> extent(imported_raster)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 143229 
xmax        : 243229 
ymin        : -564760.8 
ymax        : -464760.8 
> extent(single)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -133957.8 
xmax        : -133157.8 
ymin        : 165319.3 
ymax        : 166119.2
```

Is there a simple/efficient way of `tryCatch'ing` this? My first attempt (below) is obviously not working.

```
> try({ 
+      clip1 <- crop(imported_raster, extent(single))
+      clip2 <- rasterize(single, clip1, mask=TRUE)}) 
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap
> 
>  tryCatch({ 
+      clip1 <- crop(imported_raster, extent(single))
+      clip2 <- rasterize(single, clip1, mask=TRUE)})  
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap
```

Comment: Try nesting "try" in tryCatch.

Comment: I wound up finding a function - is.error <- function(x) inherits(x, "try-error") and then using it thusly OutExtent = is.error(try(clip1 <- crop(imported_raster, extent(single))))  and then an if statement to catch it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant nest "supressWarnings" in tryCatch. You always use an if statement to capture the error. Very useful in storing functions but also confusing in application.